# In Google Analytics, how do I figure out which domain is referring to our website the most?

Tags: google-analytics

Under the Referral Traffic tab, I get to see a list of which domains are most responsible for referral traffic to my website. Only problem is, this counts facebook.com and m.facebook.com as different domains. I want to combine all facebook domains into one, so I can hopefully get a statistic like:

50% of referrals come from Facebook
25% of referrals come from Google
25% of referrals come from Twitter

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to skip the Referrals report and use the channels report instead. If you go to Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Channels, you'll see a channel grouping for "Referrals" and a grouping for "Social". All Facebook URLs are combined under the "Social" grouping.